# how can i send 2 object in angular2 post request

Tags: java, http, angular, typescript, jersey

I have this code:

client side (angular2)

```
     saveConfig(configType: ConfigTypes, gasConfigModel: GasConfigModel): any {
        console.info("sending post request");
        let headers = new Headers({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });

....

        return this.http
          .post(this.url, formParamString, ??, {headers: headers})
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(
            data => {
              console.info("next: ");
              console.info(data)
            },
            err => console.error(err)
          );
      }
```

and

server side:

```
@Path("/SaveConfig")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public void saveConfig(MyObj my object, CountryGasStationConfig countryGasStationConfig) throws Exception {....}
```

I know how to send one object in post, but how can i send 2 object in post request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using Json as your media, it is technically impossible to achieve this, as two separate arbitrary objects in a single document would be invalid Json.

However, a potential solution here would be to create an object that wraps these two objects.

**Request Object**

```
public SaveConfigRequest {
    private MyObj myObject;
    private CountryGasStationConfig countryGasStationConfig;


    //getters and setters
}
```

**New Method Signature**

```
public void saveConfig(SaveConfigRequest request)
```

**Example Json Document**

```
{
  "myObject": {...},
  "countryGasStationConfig": {...}
}
```

Comment: Very helpful exemple ! I am using a JAX-RS2 back-end and i would like to know how can i cast those objet into java objects. i know how to do with only one object. Should i create a map with the two object or there is another way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

to send two object with different key value, 
combine them to on big object like:

```
obj1;
obj2;
obj2send={
'obj1':obj1,
'obj2':obj2
};
```

now this *obj2send* has two objects in it